# Should I convert a vector<Object> to vector<shared_ptr<Object>> in C++?

Tags: c++, json, vector

I am using the C++ json library from https://github.com/nlohmann/json.

The code I am writing is roughly similar to:

```
// User is a class
json userJson = json::parse(<...some json string...>);
vector<User> user = userJson;  // will be converted to vector<User>
```

I (personally) don't feel right to use `vector<User>` directly...
Should I convert it into a `vector<shared_ptr<User>>` (using the code below)?

```
vector<shared_ptr<User>> userPtr;
userPtr.reserve(user.size());
transform(user.begin(), user.end(), back_inserter(userPtr), [](User& item) { return make_shared<User>(std::move(item)); });
```

If both of them are not, what is the recommended way?
(for handling a list of Users/Students/Persons etc in C++)

Comment: It would make more sense to convert from `std::vector<User*>` to `std::vector<shared_ptr<User>>`. What is the problem with `std::vector<User>`?

Comment: @whoan I'm not sure... C++ beginner here, quite confused with C++'s copy/move thingy... Any resources for me on this topic? (eg, when will the object be moved/copied/etc..)

Comment: Supposing you want to avoid a copy construction, if you are using c++11 you can use move semantics to solve your problem

Comment: **No.** Always use values if possible, use pointers only if you have to.

Comment: @whoan just editied my comment (accidentally hit enter ...). How should I use and when should i use move?

Comment: @Galik uhmm.. So I should use values by default? I'm still quite confused when will C++ do copy/move...

Comment: Moving usually takes care of itself when you add a *move constructor* and a *move assignment operator*.

Comment: If you have an already created `User` object (e.g. `User myUser`), if you do a `user.push_back(std::move(myUser))`, you avoid the copy construction.. You shouldn't use `myUser` anymore. If you do a `user.push_bask(User('name'))`, the move will be automatic if you have a move constructor defined.

Comment: @Galik in the move constructor/assignment operator, what should i do? eg: what should i do if the class has other smart pointer in it?

Comment: @whoan Uhmm, the vector is actually populated by the json library, so i think it's fine to just use it?

Comment: Can I ask how std::move manages to "move" the object into the vector.  It has to copy (a memcpy type operation) presumably.  When you say "no copy" do you mean it just won't copy construct?

Comment: yes, don't copy construct, so if you have a pointer, the pointer won't be copied and freed twice for example. You need to define that `move`ment. Indeed, you will copy the pointer anyway, but you should set the previous one to `nullptr`.

Comment: @GaryNg Typically in the move ctor/assign you simply do `x = std::move(other.x);`on all the elements. If your class contains smart pointers then they should know how to move themselves. It's trickier if you are managing non-smart pointers yourself.

Comment: If you think your application, or library will ever need to scale up, pointers are the way to go.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy - that's simply untrue in the majority of cases in C++.    It MAY be true sometimes, for example if it is necessary to resort to doing dynamic memory allocation directly, rather than using a standard container.   But, practically, pointers are over-used, particularly by beginners to C++ (including C developers) who don't properly understand the standard library or how to design their classes.

Comment: @GaryNG - the recommended way would be to use data from json in form it is provided, rather than arbitrarily converting it to another form.   Working with values is better than working with pointers (including smart pointers), unless you have a SPECIFIC DESIGN REASON not to.  You "personally feeling uncomfortable" is not a specific design reason.

Comment: @Peter...  What if the list of users need to be used in different ways?  Copied, and sorted for different views?  What if these are the users for a large website?  Pointers usually end up being the solution in many cases.  And with the ease of use of smart pointers, their use is less prone to errors as it was a couple years back.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy -  standard containers and standard algorithms support using/manipulating collections in a variety of ways too, and are often optimised by design for such tasks.  I suggest you take the time to LEARN about the standard library (containers, algorithms, etc) before advocating an alternative approach. Sure, pointers have their place, but your assertion that code using pointers is more effective (in terms of developer time, run time performance, scalability, or any criterion you choose) than standard library facilities is simply false, more often than not.

Comment: It's a question of performance.  Avoiding copies whenever possible.  I've been using the stl for the last 15 years, and had not used it for the 10 years before that.

Comment: @Galik Uhm.. How about The Rule of Zero?
Should every class I created have a move constructor/assignment operator?

Comment: From what I understand, the new rule is to use let the compiler define the default implicit constructors and assignment operators whenever possible.